# Mockito How can I write a unit test for UUID generation in java?

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to create a unit test for a method that generates an id for the user.

```
public class IdFactory {
       public String generateId(){
           return UUID.RandomUUID().toString();
       }
}
```

In the unit test I am having a little bit of trouble. I cannot generate another random UUID as that would be different and I cannot make any relevant assertions. I wonder how I can go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Just assert if it is a valid UUID. You can use the [UUID#fromString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString-java.lang.String-) method.

> Creates a {@code UUID} from the string standard representation as described in the {@link #toString} method.

> @throws  IllegalArgumentException
> If name does not conform to the string representation as
> described in {@link #toString}

```
IdFactory idfactory;

@Test
public void test_generate_id() {       
    String id = idfactory.generateId();

    //asserting if the above id is a valid UUID
    UUID.fromString(id); //Should not throw an IllegalArgumentException.
}
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I just did in a test suite.

Answer (score 1):

First thought: Don't test this. The standard library already has a good test suite. You don't need to test if `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` works, it's a given.

Second thought: If you do test it, don't test the concrete implementation. Does "generate id" *have to* return a UUID? If you decide to use something else in the future, now you have to change the test. So what is the bare minimum that you need to assert? Perhaps that the ID can never be null:

```
@Test
public void testGenerateId(){
    assertNotNull(new IdFactory().generateId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As with [Mockito 3.4](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013) you *can* now mock static methods. For your simple `generateId` method, I agree with the other answers that you should not invest too much time testing the `UUID` generation. But if your logic is a little bit bigger and you want reliably generate `UUID` for your test, you *can* use the following approach.

```
UUID result = UUID.randomUUID();

// or prepare the result in this way
// UUID result = UUID.fromString("76bb18c0-86c6-446e-884d-37550247d49d");

MockedStatic<UUID> mocked = mockStatic(UUID.class);

mocked.when(UUID::randomUUID).thenReturn(result);

System.out.println(UUID.randomUUID()); // -> prints the result UUID
System.out.println(UUID.randomUUID()); // -> prints the result UUID
```